# Implement typeahead / autocomplete / suggestions with useQuery from react-query

Tags: autocomplete, typeahead, react-query

> This question is posted as self-answered; as encouraged and described [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.249731014.1917197513.1646037040-226104504.1612779616):
>
> [...] document it in public so others (including yourself) can find it later

This is `react-query` specific. How can the various options of the `useQuery` hook best be configured to support an *input suggestions* functionality (also known as autocomplete and typeahead)?

Does `useQuery` support:

- debouncing of the input value?
- only sending requests if the input value has at least 3 characters?
- caching responses for previous input values as long as the current user interaction with the text field is not over?

A naïve implementation would deal with all this in userspace (i.e. not using the library, instead implementing it all in custom code):

```
// [x] debouncing
// [x] at least 3 characters
// [-] caching
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
const { data } = useQuery([search], () => api.getSuggestions(search));
useEffect(() =>
  {
    if (value.length > 2)
    {
      const id = setTimeout(() => setSearch(value), 500);
      return () => clearTimeout(id);
    }
  },
[value]);
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/issues/293) and [here](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/discussions/1750) a `useDebounce` [hook](https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/) is the right approach; `react-query` itself does not offer a *debounce* option.

Suppressing requests until the input value has at least 3 characters can be achieved with the `enabled` option (as suggested [here](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/discussions/416)).

The `staleTime` can be tweaked so that cached previous results are still considered valid. We could use *1 minute* as a heuristic for the duration of the user interaction, results older than a minute are not re-used but fetched anew if the user interaction is longer.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
const search = useDebounce(value, 500);
const { data } = useQuery(['suggestions', search], () => api.getSuggestions(search),
  {
    enabled: search.length > 2,
    staleTime: 1000 * 60,
  }
);
```

There is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/li6n7) with an example.

Alternative Cache Invalidation:
We could use a longer staleTime and listen for `focus lost` on the input to invalidate the query.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
const search = useDebounce(value, 500);
const { data } = useQuery(['suggestions', search], () => api.getSuggestions(search),
  {
    enabled: search.length > 2,
    staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 5,
  }
);
const queryClient = useQueryClient();

<input onBlur={() => queryClient.invalidateQueries('suggestions')} />
```